# How to implement two separate services in on Serverless framework application?

Tags: aws-lambda, serverless-framework

I have on serverless app, which has many API endpoints, i ran into the popular problem of "limited 200 resources", i searched for the solution, some suggest using plugins to apply what is called "nested stacks" or multiple stacks for the same service.

Others suggest, splitting the app into more than one service, which i see is more reliable, my question is, what is the proper structure for one project containing two different services, every service has its own serverless.yml (for example, will we use one package.json at root or what ?)

any detailed examples will be appreciated

Comment: Not sure about "splitting the app" solution but I can tell you that using nested stacks is a real option - I've done it for one of my projects. Nested stacks is a real solution provided by AWS and I believe that should be used. When using nested stacks, it basically splits resources into different CloudFormation template. For example, all API gateway related resources into 1 yaml file, all lambda functions in 2nd yaml file, all permissions in 3rd yaml file, etc. One thing to keep in mind, each nested stack also has the 200 resources limit. Meaning 4 nested stacks gives you limit of 800.

Comment: Cool, how can i add nested stack to an app which already in use, i mean has its resources, permissions setup, any detailed examples to so, available online?

Answer (score 1):

The 200 resources is a "soft limit" which you can write to AWS and ask them to relax. In some cases they will let you deploy more resources than 200 if you apply for your case.

It happened to my project and what I did was splitting the API into several projects according to logical grouping of the modules. Specifically I moved out the "Users API" to a Serverless project of its own, and kept the "Resource API" in another project. Then I also used a technique like the following to reduce the consumption of resources: Instead of declaring a new handler for every REST verb (one for "post a resource" and another for "get a resource" etc) I put them in the same handler but as different events under the same handler.